# How to calculate the time complexity for $T(n)= T(f(n)) + g(n)$ type of recurrent relations?

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

How can I calculate the time complexity for $T(n)= T(f(n)) + g(n)$ type of recurrence relations? 
For example: 
$$ T(n)= \begin{cases} 1 &n\leq 1\\ T(\log_2 n) + n & n > 1 \end{cases}$$
or
$$ T(n)= \begin{cases} 1& n\leq 1\\ T(\log_2\log_2 n) + 2^n & n > 1 \end{cases}$$

I am preparing for a test so would it be possible to convert the equations somehow so that the Master theorem can be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a general way to deal with recurrence relations with a weird $f(n)$, but in these cases it's easy to show that the $g(n)$ is what dominates: if you unwind the first recurrence, you get
$$T(n)=n+\log_2 n+\log_2\log_2 n+\log_2\log_2\log_2 n + ...,$$
where the sum continues as long as the terms keep being positive. You can show by induction that if $n=2^m$ then $n\leq T(n)\leq 2n$, and that, together with the fact that $T(n)$ is increasing, is enough to show $T(n)=\Theta(n)$.